# Cursor in the Output screen of Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have noticed that when I make a menu like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Option 1");
System.out.println("Option 2"); 
System.out.println("Select your option: ");
optionSelection = input.nextInt();
```

The cursor for taking the input is behind the text, like this:

```
Option 1
Option 2
|Select your option:
```

But when I write the entire menu using one print statement like this:

```
System.out.println("Option1 \nOption2 \nSelect your option");
```

Then the cursor is placed at the **end** of the "Select your option" text. **Why's that?**

Comment: @EugenMartynov yes, i'm using Intellij IDEA on Windows 8.1. I'm just curious to know why this happens as I feel there might be some deeper meaning to this and would help me learn something new.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with IntelliJ 14.1.4 - the cursor is placed on the next line with the first snippet.

Comment: @DarekKay what do you mean?